# SQL Server string search and evaluate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server I want to evaluate a string like `1.2.30.4.50` and output with `0102300450`. Basically evaluate each number before the period and left pad it with a zero if it has a single digit and output two digits. If the number already has two digits it should be left untouched.

A string like `2.5.99.10.1` should evaluate to `0205991001`. Note there are no zeros before `99` and `10`.

I know the below query will return the 1st number before the first period occurrence. But I'm unable to take this further. Any help appreciated!

If  `col` contains a string say `1.2.30.4.50`:

```
SELECT left(col, charindex('.', col) - 1) FROM table
```

will return the below:

```
 column1    
 ---------- 
 1
```

Comment: I would recommend that you define a user-defined function for this.  This is tricky.

Comment: Code for the UDF is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Is the amount of numbers always going to be the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can as the below

```
CREATE FUNCTION PrepareString
(    
    @val varchar(max), 
    @delimiter varchar(10)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN   

    DECLARE @xml as xml 
    SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@val,@delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)

    RETURN 
        (
            SELECT
                (
                    SELECT 
                         CASE WHEN LEN(N.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)')) = 1 THEN '0' + N.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') ELSE N.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') END 
                    FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
                    FOR XML PATH ('')
                ) A
        )
END
GO
```

Example:

```
SELECT dbo.PrepareString('2.5.99.10.1', '.') -- 0205991001
SELECT dbo.PrepareString('1.2.30.4.50', '.') -- 0102300450
SELECT dbo.PrepareString('1.2.30.4.50.123.3.443.2', '.') -- 01023004501230344302
```

Comment: Very neat code, though I wonder how well it performs on larger datasets?

Comment: @iamdave I dont know, i have not tried it on big data.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to use ParseName(), but there are too many observations

```
Declare @String varchar(50) = '2.5.99.10.1'
Select right('0'+Pos1,2)+right('0'+Pos2,2)+right('0'+Pos3,2)+right('0'+Pos4,2)+right('0'+Pos5,2)
 From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row](@String,'.')
```

Returns

```
0205991001
```

The Row Parse UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
     From (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
)
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('John Cappelletti',' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not on SQL Server 2016 and can't use the `string_split` function, this type of problem is perfectly suited to [Jeff Moden's Tally Table based string split table valued function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

To create the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l

GO
```

And then combine with `for xml` to concatenate the rows to columns to get your result.

```
-- Create some data.
declare @a table(String nvarchar(100));
insert into @a values
 ('1.2.30.4.50')
,('06.7.80.90.10')
,('01.20.3.40.5');

-- This is how the function returns the data.
select Item
        ,right('0' + cast(Item as varchar(10)),2) as PadItem
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K('1.2.30.4.50','.');

-- This is how you use FOR XML to concatenate the rows back together.
select (select '' + right('0' + cast(Item as varchar(10)),2)
        from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(a.String,'.')
        for xml path('')
        ) as Result
from @a a;
```

Which give your the fllowing results:

```
Result
----------
0102300450
0607809010
0120034005
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on below:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(100) = '2.5.99.10.1' DECLARE @EvlStr VARCHAR(100) = '',@OutPut VARCHAR(100) = ''
```

WHILE LEN(@Str) > 0
BEGIN

```
 IF CHARINDEX('.',@Str) = 0
 BEGIN
    SET @EvlStr = @Str
    SET @Str = ''
 END  
 ELSE
 BEGIN

    SELECT @EvlStr = SUBSTRING(@Str,0,CHARINDEX('.',@Str))                                          
    SELECT @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str,CHARINDEX('.',@Str)+1,LEN(@Str))
 END


 IF LEN(@EvlStr) = 1
       SET @OutPut = @OutPut + '0' + @EvlStr
 ELSE 
       SET @OutPut =  @OutPut + @EvlStr
```

END

SELECT @OutPut

Comment: It's good but does not evaluate correctly. No left padding should occur if the number before the period has already two digits. So '2.5.99.10.1' should evaluate to 0205991001 instead of 020509901001.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on the following:

- Number of tokens: 5
- Min token length: 1
- Max token length: 2

---

```
select      right ('0' + ltrim (rtrim (substring (replace (col,'.','    '), 1,2))),2)
        +   right ('0' + ltrim (rtrim (substring (replace (col,'.','    '), 6,3))),2)
        +   right ('0' + ltrim (rtrim (substring (replace (col,'.','    '),11,4))),2)
        +   right ('0' + ltrim (rtrim (substring (replace (col,'.','    '),16,5))),2)
        +   right ('0' + ltrim (rtrim (substring (replace (col,'.','    '),21,6))),2)

from        tab
;
```

Comment: @Balaji, Is this solution good for you or do you need a more general approach?

Comment: I prefer a generic solution that can handle any length of numbers. Code from @neer fits the bill perfectly.